# Get YouTube API client approval

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I run a Wowza Streaming Server which sends streams to YouTube (among others). There are 43 regular streams each week. I got tired of manually scheduling the YouTube live broadcasts (spread over 4 different channels) and wrote a shell script that uses the YouTube Data API to insert a broadcast and bind it to a YouTube stream. In the Google project, the OAuth2 consent screen is verified. I requested an audit from YouTube (they thanked me for my compliance and said they didn't need anything else from me).

The problem is that the video resulting from recording the live stream is locked private for violation of their spam etc. policy.

Does anyone know what other hoops I need to jump though for this to play right? This is a simple shell script run from crontab entries on an Ubuntu server; no user interaction at all.

Comment: I recommend to address this issue directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you. Issue tracker is, evidently, not for individual problems. Here is what comes up if you search for "YouTube API help": We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags.

Comment: You're very much wrong: the issue tracker *is very much for individual problems*. Here is a quote from the [front page of YouTube Data API's official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/): **[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) Something wrong? Send us a bug report!**. This very text is to be seen on the official [How to Get Help](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) page too.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Update: submitted to Google bug tracker August 2, 2021; assigned within 4 hours; no further response after 23 days. Where are the YouTube engineers that are supposedly monitoring posts tagged with youtube-api?

Comment: There are no YouTube engineers monitoring YouTube related SO tags. Not in my experience (and of others too). That's in spite of the claims Google makes on its official doc pages.

Comment: If you go to the YouTube Data API help page, this is what it says: How to Get Help 
We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags. I guess they lied.

Comment: That claim was true many years ago, when e.g. [Ibrahim Ulukaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973552/ibrahim-ulukaya) and [Jeff Posnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385997/jeff-posnick) were active on the tags [tag:youtube-api] and [tag:youtube-data-api], while assuming publicly being voices of Google/YouTube. Nowadays the claim is unsustained.